How to retain inherited folder permissions for newly uploaded files in a Windows development environment?
In my mobile app, I need to take a photo and send it to the OpenAI API for analysis. I'm working in a development environment with a local server on my Windows PC.
Here's the code snippet that uploads the image to a folder on the server (i.e., on my PC in my development environment):
$nameOfImage = $scanning->getId() .$token. '_scanning.' . pathinfo($_FILES['photo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], './patient/files/import/scans/' . $nameOfImage);

The images are uploaded to the correct folder, and the folder has read permissions for the 'Everyone' user in Windows Security. The problem is that every time a new image is uploaded to the folder with the above code, the inherited permissions from the parent folder are not applied, and no one has permissions on the image. As a result, the image becomes unusable, and I cannot send it for analysis by OpenAI.
I tried modifying the permissions of the parent folder, expecting the new images to inherit these permissions automatically. However, the new images still default to having no permissions.

Add this code and check : chmod('./patient/files/import/scans/' . $nameOfImage, 0755) // or 0644;

@Death-is-the-real-truth unlikely to work on Windows I'd imagine
